# Despite having no datatypes for arguments and x,y are not global variables, How is this code not showing any errors and is working perfectly?

Tags: c

```
int max(x,y)
  int x,y;
  {
   return x>y?x:y;
  }
```

This code is working without any errors. Can a function take arguments without data types and later define it with specific datatype?

Comment: It's old historic syntax. In general, just don't use it.

Comment: @kaylum I saw it and thought "Thats K&R" - but it's been so long since I used it I couldn't remember if the semi-colon was right or not :-)